# Simple For-Loop results in memory exhausted error

Tags: php, date, for-loop

After working more than 4 hours on localizing the problem, I finally found the part of my code that leads to the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 8388608 bytes) in

I'm fetching data from my database. The query returns an array of data with 33 entries (not that much...)
I iterate over that array with a for-loop to get a time difference and flag the array if the difference is too big (simple if-else).... Its quite difficult to explain, but I guess you get what I mean by looking at my code... its pretty simple:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($customerList); $i++) {

        $date1 = date_create($customerList[$i]["lastUpdate"]);
        $interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);

        $min=$interval->format('%i');
        $sec=$interval->format('%s');
        $hour=$interval->format('%h');
        $mon=$interval->format('%m');
        $day=$interval->format('%d');
        $year=$interval->format('%y');

        $date3 = date("H");

        if(($year > 0) || ($mon > 0) || ($day > 0)) {
            $customerList[$i]["flag"] = 1;
        }
        else {
            if($date3 >= 6 && $date3 <= 21) {
                if(($hour > 0) || ($min > 29)) {
                    $customerList[$i]["flag"] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The variable `$date2` is defined before the for-loop with the following line of code:

```
$date2 = date_create($lastUpdateTime["lastUpdate"]);
```

Sadly I really don't see how this code can result in that error, since in my opinion this shouldn't really use that much memory...

Im 100 % sure that the error comes from this for-loop, since when I remove it the error is gone. Also, when I place this for-loop inside other views, it results in the same error.

I solved the problem by increasing the maximum memory limit of PHP, still I wonder how this for-loop can cause that problem.

I would really appreciate any explanations, since I don't find anything on the internet...

Oh, I'll just add the query here so you can see that I don't fetch a lot of data (the site handels much bigger queries without any problems...):

```
SELECT c.id, c.type, c.name, c.environment, cd.customer, MAX(cd.createdAt) AS lastUpdate FROM customerdata AS cd JOIN customers c ON cd.customer = c.id GROUP BY customer ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should use only `<` instead of `<=` in `for($i = 0; $i < count($customerList); $i++) `.

Comment: By using `$i <= count(..` in your for loop, you create new array elements inside the loop. This makes the loop run infinitely, creating a new element each time and processing it on the next iteration. You could replace the `for` loop with a `foreach`, this makes it easier to read and prevents errors like this.

Comment: You could also replace the `$interval->format()` calls with simply `$interval->i`, `$interval->s`, ... As it is now, you are taking the numbers stored in the `DateInterval` object, format them as strings, and convert the strings back to numbers.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Thank you very much for your help and your advises on improving my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop condition is `$i<=count($customerList)` instead of `$i<count($customerList)`. This means your access of `$customerList[$i]` goes one past the end of the array, creating a new element along the way. Now `count($customerList)` is one larger, so the loop takes another iteration, ad infinum, thereby using more and more RAM for the growing array.

You should also get a warning message that the element does not (yet) exist when first accessing it, when you read `"lastUpdate"`. Later, when you set the `"flag"` element, you create the array element.

To make the loop conditions easier to read and prevent typos like this, you could use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($customerList as $customer) {
    $date1 = date_create(customer["lastUpdate"]);
    $interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);
...
```